# A question about modular forms in SAGE

Tags: number-theory, math-software, modular-forms, sagemath

I was trying to solve Exercise 1.4.5 in Alvaro Lozano-Robledo's book *[Elliptic Curves, Modular Forms and Their L-functions](http://books.google.co.cr/books?id=iL6CL0IiNKsC&printsec=frontcover)*, which is about representations of integers as sums of 6 squares and its relation to the theta function

$$\Theta(q) = \sum_{j = -\infty}^{\infty} q^{j^2} $$

I need to define the space of modular forms $M_3(\Gamma_1(4))$ in [SAGE](http://www.sagemath.org/), which I already did and find a basis for this 2-dimensional space. I was able to this without any problems.

> But now I'm asked to write $\Theta^6(q)$ as a linear combination of the basis elements just found. This prompts me to ask some questions.
>
> 1) How do I define $\Theta(q)$ in SAGE and how do I check that $\Theta^6(q) \in M_3(\Gamma_1(4))$?
>
> 2) How would I express $\Theta^6(q)$ as a linear combination of the basis elements?
>
> 3) More generally, is there a way in which one can specify some q-series expansion and ask SAGE if it is in a particular space of modular forms and if it is to express it as a linear combination of the basis elements?

I've already searched in the SAGE manual but I only found how to define Eisenstein series and the like.

Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Comment: Ask at their [dedicated Q&A site](http://ask.sagemath.org/questions/), you may get your answers sooner.

Comment: @Sasha Thanks for the suggestion, but actually I already did that more than two months ago and I didn't get any answers nor comments to the question. So I basically posted my question here. This is the link to the question http://ask.sagemath.org/question/1114/how-to-define-an-element-in-a-space-of-modular

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thank you for reading my book. I am not an expert in Sage, but I can tell you what I had in mind when I wrote that problem. The goal of the exercise is to work with $\Theta^6$ replicating what is done for $\Theta^4$ in Example 1.2.1 (towards the end of Section 1.2).

Showing that $\Theta^6 \in M_3(\Gamma_1(4))$ is far from trivial and in the context of Chapter 1 of the book, and more precisely for Exercise 1.4.5, you should *assume* that $\Theta^6\in M_3(\Gamma_1(4))$. If we assume this, we can compute a basis of the space in Sage, and just use a bit of linear algebra (again, as in Example 1.2.1) to find out what $\mathbb{C}$-linear combination of the basis elements add up to $\Theta^6$. If $M_3(\Gamma_1(4))$ is $n$-dimensional, with a basis $f_1,\ldots, f_n$, then 
$$\Theta^6 = \lambda_1f_1+\cdots + \lambda_nf_n,$$
for some $\lambda_i\in\mathbb{C}$. In order to find the constants $\lambda_i$, it suffices to solve a $n\times n$ system of equations that can be obtained from the first $n$ coefficients of $\Theta^6$ and those of $f_1,\ldots, f_n$.

About your specific questions: you can define in Sage $q$-expansions up to a certain precision, but the only way you can check whether a $q$-expansion corresponds to a modular form in a certain space of modular forms is precisely to do as I point out above: find a basis of the space, and check whether your form can be written as a linear combination of elements in the space... However, you can only check that this is the case **up to a finite precision** (say $O(q^{20})$) and you will not be able to *prove* in Sage that a $q$-expansion is truly in said space. You may have found compelling evidence that a $q$-expansion corresponds to a modular form of a certain space, but you will have to go back to the theory to show that the $q$-expansion is indeed a modular form, of the given weight, and modular for the appropriate congruence subgroup.

In the particular case of $\Theta^2$, you can find the proof that $\Theta^2\in M_1(\Gamma_1(4))$, for instance, in Koblitz's "Introduction to Elliptic Curves and Modular Forms", Proposition 30 of Chapter III, Section $\S 3$.

Comment: Wow an answer from the author himself! This website is just amazing =) Thank you very much. I will try to solve it in this way then. I was frustrated for not being able to do that in SAGE. But now I understand the idea of the exercise.

Comment: @AdriánBarquero: You are welcome. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 2):

This is a late comment on an already accepted good answer from the best source. It just adds sage code, and some few words describe the decisions taken while implementing.

---

Sooner or later we will need the power series ring $R=\Bbb Q[[q]]$. We can introduce it $(1)$ explicitly as `R.<q> = PowerSeriesRing(QQ)`, or $(2)$ get it "for free" after intialization of the needed space of modular forms, then taking one such form, and finally its `parent()`. However, the `q` variable from one construction is (maybe) not the `q` variable from the other one, although in display we see "the same $q$". I will go both ways.
We have also to decide which precision is best suited for the computations.
I will use $200$, since $\Theta$ looks "superlacunary", but when printing elements of the base of the space of modular forms $M(\Gamma_1(4), 1)$ we will truncate to precision $20$. Also, note that sage already provides `theta_qexp`, however, since we will focus first on the ring used, we will delay the usage of `theta_qexp` for a better control. Hidden things that distinguish between a $\Bbb Q[[q]]$ and a $\Bbb Z[[q]]$ parent should not stay in our way for the start.

---

$(1)$

```
N = 200    # default precision below
R.<q> = PowerSeriesRing(QQ, default_prec=N)
theta = sum([q^(n^2) for n in [-isqrt(N)..+isqrt(N)]]) + O(q^N)
MF = ModularForms(Gamma1(4), 3)
print(f'MF is {MF}')
f, g = MF.basis()
```

And we get (with manual break to fit in page):

```
MF is Modular Forms space of dimension 2 
    for Congruence Subgroup Gamma1(4) of weight 3 over Rational Field
```

Since the dimension is two, and let $f,g$ be the sage generators, we can easily get the answer of representing linearly $\Theta^6$ in terms of $f,g$...

```
sage: f, g = MF.basis()
sage: f, g
(1 + 12*q^2 + 64*q^3 + 60*q^4 + O(q^6),
 q + 4*q^2 + 8*q^3 + 16*q^4 + 26*q^5 + O(q^6))
sage: theta^6 + O(q^6)
1 + 12*q + 60*q^2 + 160*q^3 + 252*q^4 + 312*q^5 + O(q^6)
```

and it is clearby looking at coefficients in $1$ and $q$ that $\bbox[yellow]{ \Theta^6=f+12g\ }$.

Digression: Also in the general case, sage provides "some order" of the elements of the basis, for instance, without any further comment:

```
sage: [f.q_expansion(12) for f in CuspForms(Gamma0(6), 8).basis()]
[q + 204*q^6 - 538*q^7 + 96*q^8 - 45*q^9 - 800*q^10 + 3570*q^11 + O(q^12),
 q^2 + 63*q^6 - 252*q^7 + 160*q^8 + 216*q^9 - 450*q^10 + 684*q^11 + O(q^12),
 q^3 - 8*q^6 + 12*q^9 + O(q^12),
 q^4 - 15*q^6 + 42*q^7 - 42*q^8 - 36*q^9 + 140*q^10 - 114*q^11 + O(q^12),
 q^5 - 6*q^6 + 15*q^7 - 16*q^8 - 9*q^9 + 48*q^10 - 49*q^11 + O(q^12)]

sage: [f.q_expansion(12) for f in ModularForms(Gamma0(6), 8).basis()]
[q + 204*q^6 - 538*q^7 + 96*q^8 - 45*q^9 - 800*q^10 + 3570*q^11 + O(q^12),
 q^2 + 63*q^6 - 252*q^7 + 160*q^8 + 216*q^9 - 450*q^10 + 684*q^11 + O(q^12),
 q^3 - 8*q^6 + 12*q^9 + O(q^12),
 q^4 - 15*q^6 + 42*q^7 - 42*q^8 - 36*q^9 + 140*q^10 - 114*q^11 + O(q^12),
 q^5 - 6*q^6 + 15*q^7 - 16*q^8 - 9*q^9 + 48*q^10 - 49*q^11 + O(q^12),
 1 + 480*q^6 + O(q^12),
 q - 128*q^4 + 78126*q^5 - 279936*q^6 + 823544*q^7 - 16512*q^8 - 2187*q^9 + 19487172*q^11 + O(q^12),
 q^2 + 129*q^4 + 2187*q^6 + 16513*q^8 + 78126*q^10 + O(q^12),
 q^3 + 128*q^6 + 2188*q^9 + O(q^12)]
sage:
```

Can we test in code $\bbox[yellow]{ \Theta^6=f+12g\ }$ ?
For a short answer pointing to the specific danger, let us compare:

```
sage: theta^6 == f + 12*g
False
sage: theta^6 == (f + 12*g)(q)
True
```

The `False` answer comes from the fact that the parents are different:

```
sage: (theta^6).parent()
Power Series Ring in q over Rational Field
sage: (f + 12*g).parent()
Modular Forms space of dimension 2 for Congruence Subgroup Gamma1(4) of weight 3 over Rational Field
sage: (theta^6).parent() == (f + 12*g).parent()
False
```

However, when we use the object $f+12g$ computed in $q$...

```
sage: ((f + 12*g)(q)).parent()
Power Series Ring in q over Rational Field
```

To have an analogy with polynomials, let us consider $p\in \Bbb Q[z]$. Then $p$ is a polynomial, but by universality, we can evaluate it in "a point" of a $\Bbb Q$-algebra, which is the "parent". In particular, $p(z)$ is such an evaluation, and $p=p(z)$ formally, the parent is kept. But else, the evaluation changes the parent. In this sense also, when building `(f + 12*g)(q)` the parent is changed to the one of `q`.

Finally, let us use the $\theta$-function which is also implemented in sage in the above context:

```
sage: theta_qexp()^6 == f + 12*g
False
sage: theta_qexp()^6 == (f + 12*g)(q)
True
```

---

$(2)$ Let us do the same by using the parent provided by the constructed modular forms in the basis. We mention only the differences that occur.

```
MF = ModularForms(Gamma1(4), 3, prec=44)
print(f'MF is {MF}')
f, g = MF.q_expansion_basis()    # already power series
R = f.parent()
print(f"R is {R}")
print(f"R has default precision {R.default_prec()}")

R.inject_variables()    # defines q
```

And we obtain:

```
MF is Modular Forms space of dimension 2
    for Congruence Subgroup Gamma1(4) of weight 3 over Rational Field
R is Power Series Ring in q over Rational Field
R has default precision 20
```

However, when printing `f` we obtain it with the declared precision `44`:

```
1 + 12*q^2 + 64*q^3 + 60*q^4 + 160*q^6 + 384*q^7 + 252*q^8 + 312*q^10
     + 960*q^11 + 544*q^12 + 960*q^14 + 1664*q^15 + 1020*q^16 + 876*q^18
     + 2880*q^19 + 1560*q^20 + 2400*q^22 + 4224*q^23 + 2080*q^24 + 2040*q^26
     + 5248*q^27 + 3264*q^28 + 4160*q^30 + 7680*q^31 + 4092*q^32 + 3480*q^34
     + 9984*q^35 + 4380*q^36 + 7200*q^38 + 10880*q^39 + 6552*q^40
     + 4608*q^42 + 14784*q^43 + O(q^44)
```

Now we can use the injected `q` from the ring `R`, which has unfortunately uncontrolled precision, it is still `20`, as printed above. (And the $q$-expansion of $f$ is computed to higher precision, without giving us access to the parent inside this computation.)

Then we define `theta`, and check the relation $\Theta^6=f+12g$...

```
sage: theta = sum([q^(n^2) + O(q^44) for n in [-10..10]])
....: theta^6 == f + 12*g
....: 
True
```

Also:

```
sage: theta_qexp()^6 == f + 12*g
True
```

(Note that now on the R.H.S. we did not evaluate in $q$.)

---

It remains to address the general question, $(3)$, given a $q$-series $F$ and a potential space of modular forms $M$ where it is / may be inside, can we check if $F$ is indeed in $M$, and if this is the case to compute $F$ as a linear combination in terms of the offered basis?

Yes, this is a linear algebra problem that can be easily implemented. But we also have *support*!

We use `theta_qexp()^6`, and try to see if it is in the claimed modular forms space `MF`. Here is the really short code for this:

```
MF = ModularForms(Gamma1(4), 3, prec=8)
try:
    F = MF(theta_qexp()^6)
    print(f'OK!\nF = {F}\nis a modular form in the space\nMF = {MF}\n\n')
    print(f'Coefficients w.r.t. the basis of MF:\n{MF.coordinate_vector(F)}')
except:
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()
```

And we get:

```
OK!
F = 1 + 12*q + 60*q^2 + 160*q^3 + 252*q^4 + 312*q^5 + 544*q^6 + 960*q^7 + O(q^8)
is a modular form in the space
MF = Modular Forms space of dimension 2 for Congruence Subgroup Gamma1(4) of weight 3 over Rational Field


Coefficients w.r.t. the basis of MF:
(1, 12)
```

To see the main used function explicitly, not inside an `f`-formatted string:

```
sage: F
1 + 12*q + 60*q^2 + 160*q^3 + 252*q^4 + 312*q^5 + 544*q^6 + 960*q^7 + O(q^8)
sage: MF.coordinate_vector(F)
(1, 12)
```

---

Let us see the same story inside an other example, where we specialize
the symmetric two variables Ramanujan series
$$
f = 1 + (a+b) + (a^2+b^2)(ab) + (a^3+b^3)(ab)^3 + (a^4+b^4)(ab)^6 + \dots
$$
in $(q,q)$, take some power, and "guess" a space of modular forms where it could live in, and check this inside a search loop.
When found, we want the coefficients.

```
R.<a,b> = PowerSeriesRing(QQ, default_prec=400)
f = 1 + sum([(a^n + b^n)*(a*b)^ZZ(n*(n-1)/2) + O(a, b)^400 for n in [1..20]])

S.<q> = PowerSeriesRing(QQ, default_prec=400)
g = f(q, q)^16

for k in [1..10]:
    MF = ModularForms(Gamma1(4), k)
    if MF.dimension() == 0:    continue    # with the next k
    try:
        G = MF(g)
        print(f'g = f(q, q)^2 is an element of:\n{MF}')
        print(f'Its coefficients w.r.t. the base of this space:')
        print(MF.coordinate_vector(G))
    except:
        pass
```

And we get (with manual breaks):

```
g = f(q, q)^2 is an element of:
Modular Forms space of dimension 5
    for Congruence Subgroup Gamma1(4) of weight 8 over Rational Field
Its coefficients w.r.t. the base of this space:
(512/17, 4096/17, 1, 32/17, 4064/17)
```

---

An other example involves eta-products.
We consider:

$$
f =
\eta(\; z\; )^6
\cdot\eta(\; 2z\; )^{-3}
\cdot\eta(\; 3z\; )^{-2}
\cdot\eta(\; 4z\;  )^7
\cdot\eta(\; 6z\; )
\cdot\eta(\;  8z\; )^{-2}
\cdot\eta(\; 12z\; )^7
\cdot\eta(\; 24z\; )^{-2}\ .
$$

Is this a modular form? It is useful to introduce the data in a dictionary:

```
dic = {1:6, 2:-3, 3:-2, 4:7, 6:1, 8:-2, 12:7, 24:-2}
```

Now we define with bare hands (so that no hidden functionality may come into play):

```
R.<q> = PowerSeriesRing(QQ, default_prec=100)
e = prod([1 - q^n + O(q^101) for n in [1..100]])    # and q^(1/24) is missing
f = prod([e(q^j)^k for j, k in dic.items()])
g = q^ZZ(sum([j*k for j, k in dic.items()])/24) * f    # add the missing part

CF = CuspForms(Gamma0(24), 6, prec=100)

try:
    G = CF(g)
    print(f'OK G = {G(q) + O(q^10)} is in the space CF:\n{CF}')
    print(f'Its coefficients w.r.t. the base of CF are:')
    print(CF.coordinate_vector(G))
except:
    print('*** Bad news is not good news in maths***')
```

And we get (manually rearranged):

```
OK G = q^2 - 6*q^3 + 12*q^4 - 6*q^5 - 13*q^6 + 42*q^7 - 72*q^8 + 30*q^9 + O(q^10) is in the space CF:
Cuspidal subspace of dimension 16 
    of Modular Forms space of dimension 24
    for Congruence Subgroup Gamma0(24) of weight 6 over Rational Field
Its coefficients w.r.t. the base of CF are:
(0, 1, -6, 12, -6, -13, 42, -72, 30, 70, -102, 108, -12, -200, 114, -108)
```

And the basis is...

```
sage: CF.q_expansion_basis(prec=30)
[
q + 48*q^19 + 114*q^21 - 312*q^23 - 491*q^25 + 120*q^27 + 1092*q^29 + O(q^30),
q^2 + 39*q^18 - 192*q^22 + 90*q^26 + O(q^30),
q^3 + 30*q^19 - 40*q^21 - 72*q^23 - 120*q^25 + 69*q^27 + 288*q^29 + O(q^30),
q^4 + 4*q^16 - 30*q^20 - 36*q^24 + 68*q^28 + O(q^30),
q^5 - 20*q^19 + 27*q^21 - 24*q^23 - 82*q^25 + 48*q^27 + 147*q^29 + O(q^30),
q^6 - 12*q^18 + O(q^30),
q^7 - 7*q^19 - 60*q^21 + 42*q^23 + 188*q^25 - 66*q^27 - 336*q^29 + O(q^30),
q^8 - 6*q^16 + 9*q^24 + O(q^30),
q^9 - 20*q^19 - 14*q^21 + 48*q^23 + 80*q^25 - 40*q^27 - 192*q^29 + O(q^30),
q^10 - 15*q^18 + 38*q^22 - 42*q^26 + O(q^30),
q^11 - 11*q^19 - 24*q^21 + 38*q^23 + 104*q^25 - 45*q^27 - 224*q^29 + O(q^30),
q^12 - 4*q^16 + 4*q^20 + 4*q^24 - 12*q^28 + O(q^30),
q^13 - 7*q^19 - 15*q^21 + 24*q^23 + 64*q^25 - 30*q^27 - 138*q^29 + O(q^30),
q^14 - 6*q^18 + 15*q^22 - 20*q^26 + O(q^30),
q^15 - 5*q^19 - 4*q^21 + 12*q^23 + 20*q^25 - 12*q^27 - 48*q^29 + O(q^30),
q^17 - q^19 - 6*q^21 + 4*q^23 + 19*q^25 - 6*q^27 - 38*q^29 + O(q^30)
]
```

(Note also how easy it is to see the first coefficients of the cusp form $G=q^2 -6q^3+12q^4+\dots$ in terms of the base chosen in sage, with elements of the shape $q^k+\dots$ with $k$ from $1$ to $17$, missing only the $16$, and with a $q^{16}$ part only for $k$ divisible by four. Else only terms in the ideal $O(q^{18})$.)